# Determine the speed of a positron after its acceleration from rest through a potential difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics

This relatively (pun intended) simple question has stumped me regarding the way to tackle it. The topic of this question is special relativity and has continued to annoy me. Let me explain why:

The question is asked in the following way:

> Determine the speed of a positron after its acceleration from rest through a potential difference $\Delta V=1000000\mathrm{V}$? Hint: use energy conservation; the potential energy loss of the particle is $e\Delta V$.

This question obviously focuses on testing my Energy conservation skills regarding relativity, we know that the energy before the acceleration is equal to $E_0=m_0c^2$ and that the kinetic energy $T$ is defined as $T=(m-m_0)c^2$ so the energy conservation equation becomes  $$m_0c^2=(m-m_0)c^2+e\Delta V$$ which can be simplified to $$m_0c^2=m_0c^2\cdot(\gamma-1)+e\Delta V$$ with $m=m_0\cdot\gamma$ which further simplifies to $$2=\gamma+\frac{e\Delta V}{m_0c^2}$$ which again simplifies to $$2-\frac{e\Delta V}{m_0c^2}=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{1/2}}$$ and again to $$\frac{3}{4}-\frac{(m_0)^2\cdot c^4}{e^2\cdot\Delta V^2}=\frac{v^2}{c^2}$$

This, however, baffles me as the question wants us to answer the speed required in a factor $c$  for example $0.8c$ which isn't the case here.

So if you can see what mistake I made it would be greatly appreciated, because it seems like I am missing an important puzzle piece.

Comment: You have $v^2/c^2$ on the right equal to a number on the left. So why are you unable to find $v$ as a fraction of $c$?

Comment: What textbook are you using that teaches relativity using “relativistic mass”? That is an obsolete concept.

Comment: Why did you include rest energy before the acceleration but not rest energy after?

Comment: If your formula doesn’t give $v=0$ when $\Delta V=0$ then you know it can’t be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your energy conservation equation is wrong.

The positron still has rest mass energy (in addition to the KE acquired) when accelerated, so you need to add $m_0 c^2$ to the right hand side – or omit it from the left!

No doubt you are bearing in mind that your $\Delta V$ is negative.

So your energy conservation equation can be written simply as:
$$m_0 c^2(\gamma -1) + e\Delta V = 0$$
or $$m_0 c^2=\gamma m_0c^2+e\Delta V$$

A word about notation... With good reason, most physicists no longer use the concept of relativistic mass. It is unnecessary and potentially confusing. The term 'mass' is reserved for a frame-independent property of a body: what used to be called 'rest mass' and denoted by $m_0$. I've retained $m_0$ in my answer above, so as not to confuse you, but $m$ is the modern symbol – as we've dropped the idea of relativistic mass for which it used to stand, so we don't need the zero subscript! $\gamma$ has its usual meaning.